# Develop an android project with codenvy

Tags: android, codenvy

I'm trying to use codenvy to develop android projects, but I don't know how I can launch the emulator to see my project running. I found this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqkHOWbFrDQ) about using manymo as a cloud based emulator but I don't know how to use it with the current version of codenvy.

EDIT : I clicked on the "run" button but I got no window poping up, here is a screen-shot of my project :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now have a built-in emulator.  When you launch the runner you'll first see a gray screen - at that point right-click and choose "Emulator" from the pop-up.  It'll take a moment to load then you should see the Android logo and then the home screen.

Comment: I don't have a pop-up window when I click on run

Comment: At the top of the Runner panel you should see a blue URL in the "Application" box.  If you click that it will open the app in a new browser tab and then you can right-click to get the emulator.