# Running android on codenvy

Tags: android, codenvy

My question is in regards to the question posed here:

[Develop an android project with codenvy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333488/develop-an-android-project-with-codenvy)

I am trying to run this android hello world app too.

"When you launch the runner you'll first see a gray screen - at that point right-click and choose "Emulator" from the pop-up"

I'm assuming they mean the blank blue screen in the VNC box which comes up when I click on the url in the application box?

However no pop-up "Emulator" comes up for me.

I am using a chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable touch events in Chrome. Go to chrome://flags/, and set variable "Enable touch events Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS" from Automatic (default) to Disabled.

It is related to the issue with touch screens in Chrome: https://github.com/zynga/scroller/issues/40